# Merging a path to another object

Tags: mesh, path

I currently have a Square based pyramid and a path that's beveled by a Bezier circle. is there any way to merge these two objects. and if so do i need to merge the path or the bevel object to the pyramid. 
[image]
This is my first real attempt at making a character model, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this one. **Alt+C** -> **Mesh from curve** then you can merge them by **Ctrl+J**